# Пропала верхняя панель админки при создании собственной темы в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Создаю свою собственную тему wordpress. При создании темы понял, что куда-то "ушла" верхняя панель админки wordpress. Если непонятно, что за верхняя панель админки wordpress, то вот фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня вот так, то есть вверху нет этой панели:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал уже приписывать к ссылке /wp-admin, но бросает внутрь wordpress, а не панельку. Я впервые делаю собственную тему на Wordpress, поэтому не возмущайтесь, если туплю :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Не хватало `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` перед тегом `</body>` в конце файла `index.php`.